# Offline.js error message

Tags: javascript, ajax, offline, offline.js

I'm using  [Offline.js](https://github.com/HubSpot/offline) library to notify users when they lost internet connectivity. Currently this library intercepts every AJAX request and decides if user have a connection.

Here's a function which is automatically called when connectivity is lost:

```
Offline.on('down', function () {
    alert('A network error has occurred.');
});
```

I was wondering if there is any chance to notify users with the **actual error message** which is  logged to console, e.g. *net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED* or *net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED*?

Comment: You will get those messages in the AJAX request error callback.

Comment: I know, but in this case I need to get those messages in this function particularly (actually I'm doing some more complex things, than alerting the users).

Comment: `Offline` does not send any parameters to the events so it is impossible with this library. Your last resort will be `window.onerror`, save the error in a variable anywhere and use it in your function.

Comment: Thank you for your response. For now I'm suspending my idea, to get those error messages in this function until management says that is essential.

Comment: You could also fork offline.js and add a parameter to the down callback, that should not be too difficult. Maybe somebody even already did it.

Answer (score 0):

That should return the error

```
 Offline.on('down', function (error) {
    alert('A network error has occurred.' + ' ' + error);
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you're not correct - how A1rPun said: "Offline does not send any parameters".